# about customizing ADFS on Windows Server 2019

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2019

In ADFS on Windows Server 2019,
We plan to set the developed authentication provider as the only authentication method.
However, if I set a custom authentication provider as the only authentication method,
There was a problem that the content customized in Onload.js had not reflected.
We have confirmed that it has been reflected in the case of default Form Authentication.

What was customized in Onload.js is that you do not need to enter the domain name when entering the user ID.
If this became ineffective, it is quite inconvenient because the input increases. 
Could you give me any advice?

Best regards,
masapiko